# How can I change the exit node used with torify

Tags: torify

I run debian 10 and have a bash script with the command `torify gpodder` to launch gpodder and download podcasts. But some podcast hosts use cloudflare, which blocks some exit nodes but not others. In tor browser I would just open new circuit, but dont know how to do that with `torify`.

is there a way to change the exit node with `torify`?

Also, lol at the error message "Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more." on the *tor* stackexchange haha